# maintaining and refreshing connections in 2D drawing

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have searched for keywords such as *2D, drawing, algorithm* but have not found or at least noticed if this could be a duplication on SOF so please let me know then I will be happy to delete it in order to follow StackOverFlow policy!

Long story short, I need to know if anybody have used or is aware of an optimized algorithm for moving a rectangle in 2D on a canvas. (Currently we are using WPF)

Here is our code and our problem is with moving object that are connected in node/point with a rectangle which being moved using mouse. Consider a scenario where user grabs a node let's say bottom right corner and drags it on canvas.

The rectangle moves OK but when it has other shapes connected to it e.g. another rectangle, line or circle. Currently it goes wrong and design/sketch goes out of shape.

I guess, to clarify my question maybe I should be asking this: Which algorithm or what kind of Data Structure can help me to track and maintain the connection of other linked shapes to this rectangle?

NOTE:  **OK, one thing I need to add up here is that our code was working fine in all cases however, we noticed that when our shape or drawing gets complicated moving the whole design or object is taking too much time.
what we had done in previous version (as far as rectangle) was connecting two lines where a list would store all the connectivity information so for a rectangle we were storing information in each Start and End point of a line. 
However, in the new version (being developed) we used an object from Point class to store 
those information. Hence, instead of storing information in 8 points we are storing connectivity information in 4 points hoping that would optimize the system. Now, we have run into this connectivity issues where moving a rectangle is not happening properly and a rectangle can turn into a broken rectangle or even a single line.
See attached snapshot please.**

```
    public void RefreshDirectConnections()
    {
        if (!this.IsTraversed)
        {
            this.IsTraversed = true;                    
            TestDrawingCanvas canvas = this.Parent as TestDrawingCanvas;

            foreach (TestConnection con in this.Connections)
            {
                TestShapeBase shape = canvas.GetByID(con.ConnectedShapeID);


                if (!shape.IsValidMove(this.GetHandle(con.ThisHandle), con.ConnectedHandle))
                {
                    InValid = true;

                    canvas.DrawInvalidRect(this.GetHandle(con.ThisHandle));

                }
                else
                {
                    shape.MoveHandleTo(this.GetHandle(con.ThisHandle), con.ConnectedHandle);
                    shape.RefreshDrawing();                        
                }
            }
        }            
    }
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the code that actually moves the shapes, and also maybe a screenshot explaining the results you are currently getting and why they are wrong?

Comment: ok working on it. I will post few snapshots soon

Comment: For a typical tree traversal there is no need to maintain state in the individual nodes (the IsTraversed property you maintain). My guess is that you don't clear all these properties everytime you move the drawing, and so only parts of the tree are only moved.
For a simpler tree-traversal look up Depth-First tree traversal for instance (there are more ways to traverse a tree) and see how the pseudocode for a recursive implementation looks. This will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: As @mbeckish suggests, the code you're using to actually move the shapes would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most 2d and 3d applications which maintain objects/vectors/things in relationship to eachother use a [scenegraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_graph).
The graph is a tree structure where every object(except the root) has a parent. Each child node has it's position defined relative to it's parent. This makes it so that if you move one child, all it's child move along automatically.
Optionally if needed you can also store relative scaling or rotation.

Comment: do you know any online resources in this regards?

Comment: I would look at gamedevelopment sites. A quick search gives me this page full of resources: http://www.gamerendering.com/2008/10/18/scene-graph/